# Django rest framework, do serializer require fields to be specified?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Let's say we have model:

```
class CompanySource(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='company_source')
    source = models.CharField(max_length=1500)
```

and we want to have seralizer for it and we use `HyperlinkedModelSerializer` it looks like this

```
class CompanySourceSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    def create(self, validated_data):
        return CompanySource.objects.create(**validated_data)

    class Meta:
        model = CompanySource
        fields = ['id', 'company', 'source']
```

is it required to set `source = serializers.CharField(max_length=1500)` inside Serliazer and what does it contribute to? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It is not important.

Rest framework serializers are designed to take the hassle out of your hands.

Refer to [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#hyperlinkedmodelserializer).

And for your case, why not use [Model serializer?](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer). You do not seem to be needing links